# Prove that $df(p)=0$ if p is a local extrema on a differentiable Manifold.

Tags: analysis, manifolds

I am supposed to prove that if $p$ is a local extrema of a function
$$f: \; M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ where M is a differentiable Manifold that
$$df_p = 0$$
Let $x$ be a map around $p$, then $x(p)$ is a local extrema of
$$g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} =\; f \circ x^{-1}$$
We can identify $dg_y$ with $Dg(y)$ (where D is the total differential).
And because g is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we know that
$$Dg(x(p)) = 0$$
But from the chain rule we also know that:
$$dg_y = df_{x^{-1}(y)} \circ dx^{-1}_y$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$ df_{x^{-1}(x(p))} \circ dx^{-1}_{x(p)} = 0$$
Because $x$ is a map, $dx^{-1}$ is a linear isomorphism between the tangent spaces.
Especially its non zero and surjective
$$\Rightarrow df_{x^{-1}(x(p))} = df_p = 0$$
But I am not really sure if this actually works, i would appreciate some feedback

Comment: it works. You could also use curves $\gamma$ through $p$ $(\gamma(0) = p)$ with arbitrary $v = \dot{\gamma}(0)$ and differentiate $f \circ \gamma(t)$, i.e. $0=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \gamma)(0)=df_p(v)$.